# How small can extension complexity be?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, linear-programming

In this article on extension complexity of regular polygons https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.08031.pdf it is mentioned that extension complexity of $n$ regular polygons should be $\theta(\log n)$. This is an exponential gap.

> 1. Can the gap be more than exponential for some non-trivial classes of polytopes such as $n$ inequalities being replaced by projection of $o(\log n)$ inequalities? What are the best known examples?
> 2. If the lower bound is $\alpha\log_2 n-\beta$ what are the sharpest tradeoffs and bounds on $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the gap is at most exponential, and this follows from a simple duality argument. (My original answer used the upper bound theorem: thanks to Emil Jeřábek for pointing out that this is completely unnecessary.)

Let $K$ be a polytope with $m$ facets in $d$-dimensional space ($d \le m-1$), whose orthogonal projection on some subspace $W$ of dimension $k$ is the polytope $L$ with $n$ facets. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $K$ and $L$ contain the origin $0$. Let $K^\circ = \{y: \langle y, x \rangle \le 1 \ \ \forall x \in K\}$ be the polar (dual) polytope to $K$. The vertices of $K^\circ$ are exactly the normal vectors to the facets of $K$, so $K^\circ$ has $m$ vertices. Then 
$$L = \{x: \langle y, x \rangle \le 1 \ \ \forall y \in K^\circ \cap W\},$$ 
and the vertices of $K^\circ \cap W$ are exactly the normals to the $n$ facets of $L$. (In other words, $L^\circ = K^\circ \cap W$.) Every $(d-k)$-dimensional face of $K^\circ$, when intersected with $W$, gives at most one vertex of $K^\circ \cap W$, so, $n \le f_{d-k}(K^\circ)$, where the right hand side is the number of $(d-k)$-dimensional faces of $K^\circ$. Since any face of $K^\circ$ is the convex hull of the set of vertices it contains, so it is uniquely determined by them, we have $f_{d-k}(K^\circ) \le 2^m$. So, an upper bound is $n \le 2^{m}$, i.e. the extension complexity of a polytope with $n$ facets is at least $\lceil\log_2(n)\rceil$.

Comment: Excellent if it is $\geq \alpha\log_2n$ can the $\alpha$ be $1-O(1)$?

Comment: I think that sounds plausible, and, if true, it must also follow from the upper bound theorem, which bounds the [$h$-vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-vector) of the polytope.

Comment: I feel it is unlikely that either $\alpha\leq1$ or $\alpha=1$ and $\beta>0$ is possible for any finite facet polytope since it seems to me that we make $n$ 'decisions' from $\log_2n$ 'measurements'. I might be wrong.

Comment: I think $\lceil-1+\log_2n\rceil$ might be doable leaving no information theoretic gap. However I do not know lower value is allowable although I would be interested in knowing.

Comment: Posted related problem https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326722/gap-between-number-of-vertices-and-extension-complexity.

Comment: I may be missing something, but each face of $K^\circ$ is uniquely determined by the set of its vertices, hence the total number is at most $2^m$ (without using any sophisticated theorem).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek oh, of course.. I should've realized the upper bound theorem is only useful when you want dimension-dependent bounds. I will simplify my answer, thanks!

Comment: @EmilJeřábek As far as I know the upper bound theorem is for convex polytopes. (I am not even sure there is a universally accepted definition of a non-convex polytope.) However, it implies an upper bound of about $n^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor}$, which is quadratically better than the one in your nice simple argument. Good to know that $n^{O(d)}$ can be proved in such a simple way, though.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I’m confused about the actual statement of the theorem. Anyway, the simple argument shows that the number of $k$-dimensional faces of a polytope with $n$ vertices is at most $\binom n{k+1}$.